# I need a scala equivalent of python urllib (for url encoding)

Tags: python, scala, urlencode

I have the following python code:

```
pair = {
            "source": {
                "foo": {
                    "name": "lang1"
                },
                "bar": {
                    "code": "deriv",
                }
            },
            "dest": {
                "foo": {
                    "name": "lang2"
                },
                "bar": {
                    "code": "deriv",
                }
            }
        } 

text = "Yo soy un hombre del mundo."

params = urllib.parse.urlencode( {"pair": json.dumps(pair), "data": text})
```

where the urlencoded params must end up like:

pair=%7B%22source%22%3A+%7B%22foo%22%3A+%7B%22name%22%3A+%22lang1%22%7D%2C+%22bar%22%3A+%7B%22code%22%3A+%22deriv%22%7D%7D%2C+%22dest%22%3A+%7B%22foo%22%3A+%7B%22name%22%3A+%22lang2%22%7D%2C+%22bar%22%3A+%7B%22code%22%3A+%22deriv%22%7D%7D%7D&data=Yo+soy+un+hombre+del+mundo.

Also you will see I need a json.dumps() equivalent in scala as well. I am having difficulty identifying a scala solution that can replace this entire python approach. I would be grateful for any help. Thank you